# Is there an elegant way in Raku to see if two ranges overlap?

Tags: raku

Is there an elegant way to see if two ranges have any overlap?

For instance, if

```
my $r = 1..10;
my $r1 = 2..5;
my $r2 = 7..15;
```

then `$r1 ~~ $r` is `True`.  But `$r ~~ $r1`, `$r2 ~~ $r`, `$r ~~ $r2` are all `False`.

Is there an elegant way to do this, and optionally even determine the overlap?

I can do (e.g.) `$r ∩ $r1`, but that creates a `Set` instead of a `Range`, and isn't feasible for huge ranges.

The following does the trick, but if there is a more elegant, built-in way, I'd prefer that.

```
sub infix:<∩>(Range $r1, Range $r2)
{
    my ($min1, $max1) = $r1.int-bounds;
    my ($min2, $max2) = $r2.int-bounds;
    return Nil if $max1 < $min2 || $max2 < $min1;
    return max($min1,$min2) .. min($max1,$max2);
}

my $r = 1..10;
my $r1 = 2..5;
my $r2 = 7..15;

say $r ∩ $r1;   # 2..5
say $r ∩ $r2;   # 7..10
say $r1 ∩ $r2;  # Nil
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in. There's [a Raku entry for a related Rosettacode task](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Range_consolidation#Raku). And @librasteve very recently published [`Math::Interval`](https://raku.land/zef:librasteve/Math::Interval).

Comment: Imo ranges, used as intervals, need refinement. They have things like open/closed endpoints (either exactly such-and-such, or epsilon short of such-and-such) and positive and negative infinity, and so on. I think the operations we have need refinement, and further built in operations are needed. There are limits to what ought be built in, which is why @librasteve created their new module, but I'm currently thinking union, intersection, and consolidation ought be built ins, and the only reason they aren't is lack of tuits. I might be wrong, but if I'm right, do you have any? 

Comment: @raiph, thanks for the feedback.  Unfortunately, no tuits from me to dive into the Rakudo source.  (I shouldn't even be doing Advent of Code, where I ran into this. )

Comment: There's not a built in way to see if two ranges intersect (which delving into sets). The quickest way I've found to test for intersection is 

$r1.min <= $r2.max && $r2.min <= $r1.max 

Range::SetOps (which I need to finish) does change a bunch of the Set Operators to work on Ranges without turning them into Sets.

Comment: Thanks, @ScimonProctor!  That's pretty much how I ended up doing it.  (Before I changed my mind and did things completely differently. ;-) )

Comment: @raiph - my Math::Interval module resolves the open/closed endpoints by removing cats ears ... so there's just the two endpoints as Reals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how this works with my [Math::Interval](https://raku.land/zef:librasteve/Math::Interval) module:

```
use Math::Interval;

my $i0 = (1..10).Interval;
my $i1 = (2..5).Interval;
my $i2 = (7..15).Interval;

## smartmatch ~~ does the same as for Range ("x is contained by y")
say $i1 ~~ $i0;  # True
say $i0 ~~ $i1;  # False
say $i2 ~~ $i0;  # False 
say $i0 ~~ $i2;  # False

# cmp returns Nil on overlap (ie overlaps are not ordered)
say $i1 cmp $i0;  # Nil 
say $i0 cmp $i1;  # Nil 
say $i2 cmp $i0;  # Nil 
say $i1 cmp $i2;  # Less    NB. this is $i1 vs $i2!

#  ∩ [also (&)] gives the intersect as an Interval (ie a subset of Range)
say $i1  ∩  $i0;  # 2..5 
say $i0  ∩  $i1;  # 2..5 
say $i2  ∩  $i0;  # 7..10 
say $i1  ∩  $i2;  # Set()   NB. this is $i1 vs $i2!

say ($i1  ∩  $i0) ~~ Range;  # True
```

There are a couple of wrinkles here, but I believe that substantially this provides what you need and you will accept this Answer.

- its provided via a raku module you have to install with `zef install Math::Interval`
- you need to use the `.Interval` coercion methid to convert a standard raku Range to an Interval (which is a subset of Range so can then be used interchangeably)
- the intersect operation returns an Interval (which is a subset of Range) so will do what you need, except when there is no overlap ... in that case it gives back ∅ (aka the null Set())

I am open to changing this in the module, perhaps we need to specify what is meant by the null Range, eg. Nil..Nil ? I have made an issue for this [here](https://github.com/librasteve/raku-Math-Interval/issues/1), all f/back welcome!

Comment: Nice, @librasteve!  If this were real code instead of just Advent of Code, I'd probably refactor it to use it.  One thing that is a but surprising, is that `(10..20).Interval ∪ (30..40).Interval` appears to result in `(10..40).Interval`.

Comment: @mscha - that's a bug - now fixed by "union returns a disjoint multi-interval unless args intersect"

Answer (score 3):

For fullness of info here on SO, there is the Range::SetOps module...
https://raku.land/zef:Scimon/Range::SetOps

but these ops give back a Set which you (sensibly) do not want